# What information should be on a QSL card?

Tags: qsl-card

Like it says in the title. When you design a QSL card (intended for use for both local VHF-and-up contacts as well as international HF contacts), what information needs to be present, and what information might be considered "nice to have" but not strictly needed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

QSL cards vary greatly in design and is one of those areas of creativity.  Some hams end up with fancy double sided full color cards, spending a lot of $$.  But they could be simple as well; just text with the pertinent information on it.

Need to have info:

- Your call sign (on both sides)
- Your mailing address (so you can receive a reciprocal card)
- Details of the contact:

  - Call sign of the remote station (thanks Michael)
  - band or frequency of contact
  - mode of contact (SSB/FM/CW/etc)
  - date of contact (in UTC)
  - time of contact (in UTC)
  - signal report
  - whether or not you want a reciprocal card

Nice to have info:

- Your [Maidenhead Grid Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maidenhead_Locator_System) location
- Your county (in the US)
- Your Lat / Long
- A cool picture of your area to make them wish they lived in the same paradise you do :)

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'm almost ashamed to point out that it doesn't include the remote station's call sign under information that is needed. :)

Comment: Doh! That's what I get for answering before caffeine!

Comment: I just designed my first QSL card and forgot the same thing: the remote station.